# How do I get rid of the scrollbars on the page?

Tags: html, css

I know the answer to this is going to be simple, but I have a pretty simple HTML page, with 3 divs - header, map_canvas, and sidebar. I have some CSS to put all of this where it needs to go. But for some reason I am getting scrollbars in the browser window, and I don't want them there, I just want the page to fit the height and width of the window nicely. Any help is much appreciated.

My page is made up of this HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSS Exercise</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <input id="lat" type="text" />
            <input id="lng" type="text" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>​
```

And this CSS:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
}

#logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#map_canvas {
   float: left;
   width: 80%;
   height: 100%;
}​
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/VTR5H/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will hide any overflow and prevent scrollbars from being displayed.

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I knew it was this simple. Thanks. Is there a trick to adding a margin at the bottom of the map_canvas and sidebar divs when using overflow:hidden?

Comment: You can use `padding-bottom:10px` to set internal padding on your divs if you want some space at the bottom.

Comment: padding-bottom on the divs didn't do anything.

Comment: if you have more text than the pre-defined height, Extra height will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden,` to your `body` CSS declaration

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve this is to use `overflow-x: hidden;` inside your `body` tag.